# Loading Boostrap Tabs via Ajax call from Link Click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have outputted in a while statement a table of links, once one of the links are clicked a function is called which goes of and pulls data back including bootstrap tabs.

I can get the data back but the tab function doesnt work?

HTML Page

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" pID="<?php echo $row['p_id'];?>" class="viewP">
<div id="pinfo"></div>
```

JQuery Function

```
$(".viewP").click(function(pID) {

    var checkID = $(this).attr("pID");

    $.post('assets/ajax/p-info.php', {pid: checkID}, function(data) {
            $('#pinfo').html(data)
    });
});
```

PHP file which pushes back to the HTML file

```
<div class="block-content">
<div class="block">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-alt nav-justified" data-toggle="tabs">
    <li class="active">
    <a href="#btabs-alt-static-justified-home"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Checks</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#btabs-alt-static-justified-profile"><i class="fa fa-info"></i> Info</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

everything works with the data being pulled through but the tabs wont work?

Any help would be much appreciated.